# Need help creating a triangle in Java

Tags: java

Good morning helpful strangers ^^. I am in an intro class, and the semester is almost over! (finalllyyyyy), but I've come across a homework that I cannot figure out, and I need some help! I've been searching the questions thread for any help, but my type of homework problem is different than some of the posts I've seen here. I'll insert the question:

Write a method to display a pattern that user input a level number 
(integer) 
and use nested loops that display the following patterns with input level number. Show the error message if the level number is out of bound.
The method header shows as following.

**public static void displayTriangle(int lev)**

Notes:
do not have any space between "1" at the lowest row and "BUILD SUCC ..."

I've been having trouble with methods so for that I will be going to tutoring on Tuesday. But I just cant figure this out. This is what I have so far, but nothing is working and it's stressing me out.

If anyone could please give me advice or help I would appreciate it forever. I just want to understand! I know my level number is supposed to be the rows, and I made j the columns. But it's not doing that in my program. Thanks for your time!

--Zane <3

```
package homework.pkg12;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a level number from (1-9): ");
        int levelNumber = input.nextInt();
        levelNumber = 1;   
            for(int i = 1; levelNumber < 10; i++){
                displayTriangle(levelNumber);
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("Please only enter a number from 1-9. Try again.");
    }

    public static void displayTriangle(int lev){
        for(int j = 1; j < 10 - lev; j--){
            System.out.println(lev + " ");
            lev += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Going to tutoring is a good idea; honestly when you are starting this stuff it's very useful to get as much help as possible.  In the meantime, draw a picture of exactly what you want for say `lev = 4` and then count up the spaces **and** stars you need to print out.  It will help you figure it out.

Comment: Hi! I have actually tried that, and I understand what I want to do on paper. But when it comes to actually writing the code, I cant get it to do what I want. It's just making me feel discouraged and dumb. Thank you for your advice though <3 I appreciate it. :)

Comment: Also, thank you to everyone that has edited my code XD I know it was sloppy, but I forgot to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Don't feel dumb, this is a tricky problem if you are new.  The next step is to try to write loops to print out what you need.  Concentrate on one case (again maybe for `lev = 4`) and try to get at least that one right.  I'll point out that the assignment said to use **nested loops** but you have only one loop in your `displayTriangle()` method.  (Having some stuff worked out even on paper is a good way to impress your tutor and get extra help from them.  I know, I've been a tutor.)

Comment: Okay what you just said actually hatched an idea in my head. I remember my professor telling us, put the conditions in the method, and do the printing in the main. Ill let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your assignment correctly, you should have a main function that gets input from the user, checks if the input is in the range of 1-9. If so, calls `displayTriangle()` so it can display a triangle. If not display an error message. In pseudo-code:

```
main: 
    print "Enter a level number from (1-9): "
    get levelNumber from input
    if (levelNumber > 0 and levelNumber < 10):
            displayTriangle(levelNumber)
    else::
        println "Please only enter a number from 1-9. Try again."
```

For `displayTriangle(lev)` to give the output shown in your example, it should display, in a single line, the numbers from 1 to `lev`. Decrease `lev` by one and then, while `lev` is not zero, repeat everything. In pseudo-code:

```
displayTriangle(lev):
    while lev > 0:
        for (i = 1; i <= lev; i++):
            print i + " "
        println
        lev--
```

Comment: Hi SiggiSv! Thank you for your help, what you put worked completely! I had the main part down, but ended up struggling with the displayTriangle method part! Markspace helped me by making me realize that I wasn't using nested loops. So I went back and started from scratch again. When I got to the for loop, I didn't realize to make it a <= instead of <. Then I kept setting it to i < 10. The solution was so simple, I can't believe it. But now I feel so guilty that I was given the answer. I mean, I was close. But... . So when I see my tutor I'm going to ask them to make other triangles with me.

Comment: You are so smart, thank you soooooo much!! I even did 10 - lev. Now I'm just so embarrassed. But I guess this is how one learns. XD

Comment: @ZanesFUNNY There are actual numerical methods for figuring this sort of thing out, with out having to guess.  *Forward difference* would work here I think.  Also, "Numerical Methods" is often offered as a class at university, ask your professors and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is broken

```
levelNumber = 1;   
for(int i = 1; levelNumber < 10; i++){
        displayTriangle(levelNumber);
```

in `for` you are increasing `i` but your control variable is `levelNumber` it only tries to show `i`' value and never stops

Comment: Thank you for your advice! (and the clean up of my code, it was a mess lol).